# How do I randomly obtain the name of a data node in the cluster?

Tags: dolphindb

I want to use the rpc function to randomly distribute tasks to the data nodes in the cluster. How to get the name of a data node randomly?

Answer (score 0):

The following script will work:

```py
rand(pnodeRun(getNodeAlias).node, 1)
```

For more details on these functions, please refer to the [UserManual](https://www.dolphindb.com/help/index.html)